# Float compare with zero in swift

Tags: swift, compare

I just tried to compare a float in a while loop with zero

```
var value:Float = 10000

while (value > 0.0) {
        value = value / 1000
}
```

The strange thing is, that the condition is alway true. Even if the `value` way smaller then `0.0`. My question is, why is that happen?

If I compare `value` with `1.0` is works like expected.

Comment: value way smaller than 0.0, do you mean a negative number? Your code won't set your `value` to negative, but a very small positive float.

Comment: Ah yea that is probably my misunderstanding. With way smaller I mean 0.00001 for example

Comment: Then the `while` case is obviously always true. 0.00001 is still > 0.0.

Comment: Yea thats it. Thanks for that! Now I got it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comment, Your code won't set your value to negative, but a very small positive float.

The while case is obviously always true. `0.00001` is still > 0.0.